# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.3; Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Following are the dependencies I used

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

ERROR:- Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2 AND Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You try it.

```
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
```

Comment: I did. Now, after running the program it gives the error stating,    ERROR:- Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzdt found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.0)

Comment: I also tried adding the-->  android.useAndroidX=true and -->android.enableJetifier=true, in the gradle.properties file, it still is'nt working

Comment: Thankyou, its working now. I used these versions     -->
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.1'